# Install Qt hangs on 10%

Tags: qt

I was trying to install Qt in 64 bit Centos7 for several times. Installation hangs on 10% each time. How to solve this problem?
  [image]

In console, the get the following error/warning :

> [803090] Warning: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence:
>   22177, resource id: 31499675, major code: 40 (TranslateCoords), minor
>   code: 0 [803103] Warning: QFile::remove: Empty or null file name
>   [me@localhost ~]$ ./qt-unified-linux-x64-3.0.4-online.run  [4317]
>   Warning: No QtAccount credentials found. Please login via the
>   maintenance tool of the SDK.

Comment: download the offline installer :)

Comment: *Please login via the maintenance tool of the SDK.*

Comment: Where I can get offline installer? They provide only online ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing it using the following command : You can retrieve it [here.](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.1/5.1.1/qt-linux-opensource-5.1.1-x86_64-offline.run.mirrorlist)

```
sudo ./qt-linux-opensource-5.1.1-x86_64-offline.run
```

Although before you do this, make sure you have installed the **development tools**, **glibc-devel.i686**.

If you don't have it, you can install it using these commands.

```
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
sudo yum install glibc-devel.i686
```

Ofcourse, make sure that you have gcc as well.

Comment: Where I can get qt-linux-opensource-5.1.1-x86_64-offline.run file?

Comment: [here](https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.1/5.1.1/qt-linux-opensource-5.1.1-x86_64-offline.run.mirrorlist). Hope it helps you out !

Comment: Install is fine, but got error while compile /usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:10: error: gnu/stubs-64.h: No such file or directory
 # include <gnu/stubs-64.h>
                           ^

Comment: The `glibc-devel` package contains the `stubs-64.h` file. Install it using the last command given.

Comment: but i have installed `glibc-devel`. I suppose I need somehow to tell Qt Designer about that

Comment: Package glibc-devel-2.17-222.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Comment: Then check in `/usr/include` if the `stubs-64.h` file is indeed present or not ?

Comment: I found `/usr/include/gnu/stubs-32.h` and `/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h` while my system is 64 bit. But no `stubs*` in `/usr/include`

Comment: I did `sudo yum install glibc-devel` and now got error cannot find -lGL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172002/discussion-between-vishaal-shankar-and-vico).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it doesn't like the fact that you're not logged in. Give the login a try.

Comment: login not helped. Got the same result - 10%